# sumar datos de una columna con un rango de fechas en c# entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

[![Hola que tal, estoy utilizando MySQL con c# entity para un proyecto de facturación web, el detalle esta que no se como poner un rango de fechas en una consulta de tipo Sum, si se dan cuenta me marca un error al agregar los operadores para separar la instrucción:

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZooCD.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZooCD.png)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que colocar un where para filtrar por fecha. La expresión que va dentro del sum es para indicar la propiedad a sumar (no el filtro)

```
var resultado = _dbFacturasEmitidas.Where(a=>a.Fecha>=fechaInicial && fe.Fecha<=fechaFinal);
if(resultado!=null){
  homeModel.MontoCFDI = Convert.ToInt32(resultado.Sum(a=>a.Total));
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero  después de ese detalle tengo un problema ya que no me acepta valores de tipo doublé ya que mi columna los datos son de tipo doublé y me causa detalles al hacer la consulta , ya intente castearlo y lo que me arroja es lo siguiente, que podria hacer en ese caso

Comment: @KevinMT Actualicé la respuesta, intenta y me avisas. Además debes borrar lo otro que pusiste como respuesta, cualquier antecedente nuevo debes hacerlo editando tu pregunta original

Comment: Ya implemente el codigo y estuve  investigando en otros foros, despues de ejecutar la instruccion me sale este nuevo error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'The cast to value type 'System.Double' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.'  pero ya lo converti a tipo int y me sigue saliendo lo mismo, ya actualize la imagen

Comment: @KevinMT Edita tu pregunta (aprovecha de sacar la foto y colocar el código como texto) y pon además la clase donde está Total, fechaInicial , etc. Necesito verificar algunas cosas de ella